# How to use cd terminal command in Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, raspberry-pi, cd

**Question**

How can I change the active directory on the raspberry pi using `cd` and the `subprocess module`?

**Background**

Since I absolutely *hate* to use the command line, I am trying to create a basic GUI text-editor which can also compile my programs. For now, I am just trying to change the directory to `Desktop`. To do this, I am using the `subprocess` module. Here is my current code:

```
from subprocess import *
call(["cd","Desktop"])
```

In the terminal, this line (`cd Desktop`) would change the active directory to `Desktop`. Oddly, when I run it through `subprocess`, I am given this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Tech Specs**

Raspberry Pi Model B

Raspbian "Wheezy" OS

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but LSTerminal seems to be where I have to do most of the things on my Pi. The terminal is what makes Linux unique in my mind, because Windows and Apple do not use it for as much functionality. I recommend trying to use it more, just to get the hang of it. It is very useful.

Answer (score 5):

I would try `os.chdir`

```
import os
os.chdir("/path/to/dir")
```

Comment: That seems to work. But, is it possible with `subprocess`? I have heard that `os` is becoming obsolete.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx `os` itself is not becoming obsolete, but `os.system` is.

Comment: [os is not becoming obsolete anytime soon](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html)

Comment: Try this subprocess.call('cd /path', shell=True)

Comment: That (comment) won't do what you expect. That will change the directory for the shell, and then immediately exit that shell.

Comment: I think that the issue was that I was not using the full path `/home/pi/Desktop`

Comment: @kojiro  Also, how can I get the program to output the errors and what not from the console. Since I just got over this hurdle, the next line `subprocess.call(["gcc",name, "-o", exe_name])` seems to have frozen. I will post the rest of the code in the question, unless everyone thinks that I should post it in another question.

Comment: please also note that you cannot change the working directory with `call`. You'll change the directory only in the subprocess. to better understand try this: `print os.getcwd();call("cd ..", cwd=os.getcwd(), shell=True);print os.getcwd()`

Comment: @xxmbabanexx if i am not wrong then, You need to pass `subprocess.PIPE` for the stderr, stdout, and/or stdin parameters.

Answer (score 1):

i don't mean to derail the original question, but if you're trying to automate a lot of tasks, you can use the `fabric` module.

it has a rather simple syntax like this:

```
with cd('/path/to/app'):
    with prefix('workon myvenv'):
        run('./manage.py syncdb')
```

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/context_managers.html

it's designed for remote usage over ssh, but many people use it for a lot of local management & deployment

the `lcd` command works on your local machine:

```
with lcd('/path/to/app'):
    with prefix('workon myvenv'):
        run('./manage.py syncdb')
```